# How to transfer OCR text from one PDF to another PDF?

Tags: pdf, ocr, ghostscript

I have two versions of one same scanned PDF. One of them has an OCR layer. How can I transfer the layer to the other one? I already install Ghostscript, but I don't know what to do next.

[How to Use Ghostscript](https://www.ghostscript.com/doc/9.52/Use.htm#Input_control)

Answer (score 1):

There's no such thing as an 'OCR layer' in PDF.

Most likely what you have is a PDF file which has a scanned image and the text extracted from that image using OCR which has been drawn as 'invisible' text (text rendering mode 3).

In general you can't copy and paste text between PDF files, so it's very hard to do what you are asking. I don't know of any tools which will help you here, I can say for certain that Ghostscript absolutely will not help you at all.

Most likely you will also need to copy the Font (or CIDFont) from the PDF file as well, and if it has a ToUnicode CMap you'll definitely also want that or search won't work (and there's little point in this sort of OCR otherwise).

Since you have a PDF file which includes the OCR'ed text, why not simply use that PDF ? I can't see any reason why you would want to 'transfer' it to another PDF file.

Comment: Why is there no way to extract that text and import it to another file? After all there are programs that can generate such text when there is none, so why can't it be used again? As for why not simply use that file, the OCR generator probably works better in original images. The other file is a whiten one using [ScanTailor Advanced](https://github.com/4lex4/scantailor-advanced). It's easier for the eyes to read, but the OCR result is not as good

Comment: If you have outputs of specific programs on your mind, it should be feasible to implement a program to copy these text. You should enhance your question to include those details and also tell us the programming language and pdf library you are using.

Comment: I didn't say that there's no way to do such a thing, I said 'in general' you can't copy and paste between PDF files. I then went on to add that you need to do more than 'copy the text'. THis isn't a trivial undertaking, though yes clearly its possible. You can't easily add text to PDF files generally. In the specific case you have here its plausible to do so, but non-trivial.

Comment: I open a new question for this. Hope to see you there [What steps to copy text from one PDF to another PDF?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61066590/3416774)